# How to read zipfile as StreamContent from httpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, zip, httpresponsemessage

I send a zipfile as a response.Content:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Package")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetLogsPackage()
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);                     
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
       using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Read((Path.Combine(path, opId.ToString()) + ".zip")))                
       {
           zipFile.Save(stream);
           response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
           response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
           response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
       }
   }
   return response;
}
```

how to get  this stream after call to this method? My code doesn't work( can't read as zipfile)
I send stream.lenght ,for example, 345673, but receive response with 367 lenght.
What is wrong?

```
  var response = await _coreEndpoint.GetLogsPackage();
  using (var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
  using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Read(stream))
   {   //do something with zip-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be `await`'ing `ReadAsStreamAsync`:

```
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
```

Currently your code is passing a `Task<Stream>` to `ZipFile.Read`, which is probably not what you intend.